# Template not found error - Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I have worked through the examples in the documentation for the Fat Free Framework, and there is one example that I cannot get to work.  It is the following:

```
$f3=require('lib/base.php');
$f3->route('GET /',
    function($f3) {
        $f3->set('name','world');
        $template=new Template;
        echo $template->render('template.htm');
        // Above lines can be written as:
        // echo Template::instance()->render('template.htm');
    }
);
$f3->run();
```

I receive an error that the Template is not found.  The error points to the line in which the template.htm file is being rendered and complains of Preview->render (i.e. its superclass, instead of Template->render).  I don't even see a file for a Preview class in the codebase.

Interestingly, if I use the same file for the View example (below), it works just fine.

```
$f3=require('lib/base.php');
$f3->route('GET /',
    function($f3) {
        $f3->set('name','world');
        $view=new View;
        echo $view->render('template.htm');
        // Previous two lines can be shortened to:
        // echo View::instance()->render('template.htm');
    }
);
$f3->run();
```

However, if I am going to use this framework, I would like to be able to utilize its templating feature as well.

Does anyone with experience with this framework have any idea what could be the problem?  I downloaded the code from Github (https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree).

Comment: One difference I can see between `View` and `Template` is that the latter needs the `TEMP` directory (default: `tmp/`). Make sure that this directory exists and is writable.

Comment: when you use the `Template` class, make sure that the `UI` var is set to the path where the `template.htm` file is.

Comment: Both of these comments helped me fix the problem!!  Thank you so much!  If one of you wants to combine both into one solution, I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 2):

By default F3 uses the same folder where is located your main file (where you start the framework instance). You can change this behavior by setting a new path for the `UI` parameter. In short:

```
$f3 = \Base::instance();
$f3->set('UI', path_to_your_templates);
```

let's say you have the following structure:

```
- app
-- views
--- template.htm (your template)
- public
-- index.php (where your init the framework)
-- (template files are expected here by default)
```

public/index.php looks like:

```
$f3 = \Base::instance();
$f3->set('UI',  __DIR__.'/../app/views/');
$f3->route('GET /',
function($f3) {
    echo  Template::instance()->render('template.htm');
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use .html instead of .htm. Yep, it really matters.

Comment: Why do you say that? It shouldn't matter. The framework doesn't care about the template file extension.

Comment: Because I'm pretty sure we had that issue in the past which could've been fixed by renaming the files to .html.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience using `fat free framework`, but a general pointer on how to debug this issue.

Apparently the file not found exception is being thrown by some code inside fat free framework. Try debugging that using [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this issue with version Fat Free Framework 3.5.1

The issue appears since the framework OOB (in at least this version) is wired with a sample such that the templates are looked for in the 'ui/' subfolder of the root fat free framework folder.

What tells me that?  Well... the OOB config.ini has the following contents:

```
[globals]
DEBUG=3
UI=ui/
```

To easily solve the problem either:

1. Put the file 'template.htm' in the 'ui/' subfolder

OR

2. Rename the 'ui/' subfolder to whatever you like in the config.ini and put the 'template.htm' file in that location

TIP:  Make sure whatever UI path you specify ends in a / and if you need to specify multiple paths you can use the | or , or ; separators (making sure each path ends in a /)